# Render repeatable widget fields properly with Backbone.js

Tags: widgets, javascript, backbone, underscore

I wanted to create widgets with repeatable fields for testimonials, time tables etc..

I recently stumbled up on this [tutorial](https://codeable.io/how-to-create-a-wordpress-testimonial-widget-with-backbone/) from codeable.io. I have some good experience with standard backbone.js as well. I completed the tutorial and implemented it.

This tutorial uses backbone.js/ underscore.js template engine to render repeatable fields.

Here is the widget [code](https://gist.github.com/usablewp/b2a899aaad54c95262d27293b0cf1006) and corresponding backbone.js [script](https://gist.github.com/usablewp/7f24de7547ef962af75afe875ea122b0).

However there is one problem that is making me sleepless since a week. Widget is working properly only after hitting the save button.

When the widget is added to a sidebar, Apart from the default testimonial, testimonials added with "add new testimonial" button are gone after hitting the save button. Functionality is working as expected only after manually hitting the save button. Only after hitting the save button, testimonials added with "add new testimonial" are saved.

After some trail and error i figured out that the problem is with widget id (possibly), when the template is rendered,`widget-testimonials_widget-__i__` is printed in the javascript template instead of actual widget id like `widget-testimonials_widget-5`. But after hitting the save button, functionality is working as expected with actual widget id. This is my problem. and here is the screenshot.

[image: The Problem. Look at the Chrome Dev Tools].

The functionality is working as expected in Proteus theme Cargo Press with out hitting the save button, although the code has several improvements like sanitization and code organization. This is screenshot of the proteus theme widget with widget id rendered properly immediately after adding widget to the sidebar. Here is the screenshot.

[image]

What should I do to render widget ID to a backbone.js / underscore template, immediately after adding the widget to a sidebar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, Finally got it to work.Use Mustache or Handlebars template system instead of underscore.js template system. Some how wordpress widget environment is not getting along with underscore template system.

Comment: that is unlikely to be "the solution". Executing any type of script embedded in a widget is a bad idea. It might be that one library have harder time than others, but you are taking a risk with doing that. It might work with current version and break with the next

Comment: you might want to read this to get insight on the why of the `__i__` https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/265170/why-is-the-unrendered-widget-number-i-showing-up-in-the-javascript-but-not/265196#265196

Comment: I can take the first comment as an answer. I always wanted to develop high standard wordpress themes. Since the above idea is coming a respectable site, I thought it is a good idea. Anyway, instead of Backbone or Angular, I will go with vanilla js to add repeating fields functionality to a widget. Thank you :)

Comment: My JS framework mojo is very weak, so you should not trust me on that. I know that the customize team want to move into having widgets working with backbone and friends so maybe it s a good idea to pop up on the slack channel and ask there

Comment: Yeah I will try that...between, Backbone, Handlebars, Widgets are playing nice with each other. After fixing the issue I have the tested the widget in various ways. It looks reliable :)

Comment: Would you share the code for the solution please? I'm having the same issue with the widget. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/nareshdevineni/03845b69cc05644a8c2920f3aba0415c

Comment: Please msg me if you have any doubts :)